# android device is ignoring ARP queries

Tags: java, android, arp

I'm writing an android app where I need to communicate with a computer on a wifi network. All the code is in java and the wifi network is an ad hoc network. In order to connect I start by sending a NBNS broadcast name query for for the machine I wish to connect to from my phone. Most times this works as expected(about 3 or 4 out of 5 times). Sometimes though, the name query fails. In either case when I send out the name query, right after I see the name query packets on the machine I'm attempting to connect to(using wireshark), I see an ARP query go out looking like...

HonHaiPr_69:a0:67   Broadcast   ARP 42  Who has 192.168.1.2?  Tell 192.168.1.10

That's the card from the computer I'm attempting to connect to asking who has my phone's address. On success, my phone dutifully replies with an ARP response...

SamsungE_75:46:bb   HonHaiPr_69:a0:67   ARP 42  192.168.1.2 is at 98:0c:82:75:46:bb

Once my phone answers the ARP query, I can then go on and communicate with the computer. The name query fails though when those ARP queries seem to go ignored by my phone. I never see an ARP response and the NBT query I put out winds up timing out. I have tried every form of datagram/socket initialization available to me in the standard java packages and nothing helps. I have researched writing my own arp response packets out, but because of where on the stack ARP is located, I need to have access to raw socket programming capabilities, which means I have to root my phone. This is an unacceptable solution for me because I want the average android user to be able to use this app without having to do anything special to their phone or their wifi network. If any of you have experienced this problem before and solved it, could you please let me know the magic formula? Thanks in advance for any input you can offer.

Comment: It seems to me that this is a problem with your Android networking configs, not a programming problem. And given that you have (understandably) precluded rooting the device, the problem CANNOT be addressed in Java.

Comment: I fear that's also the conclusion I'm starting to come to. If it is, it's a problem with android in general because it happens on multiple devices. It could also be a problem with the router, but I don't know why sometimes arp packets would make it to the phone and sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

Android appears to completely ignore ARP query. I have 3 android phones and a chromecast device on my network among other devices. As you can see below android devices never respond to ARP query.

```
root@cheetah:~# tcpdump -i wlan0 -v arp
tcpdump: listening on wlan0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
13:17:00.378724 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has cheetah tell viper, length 28
13:17:00.378747 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply cheetah is-at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (oui Unknown), length 28
13:17:14.969613 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has android-xxx tell viper, length 28
13:17:32.562764 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has android-yyy tell viper, length 28
13:17:32.606825 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has cheetah tell selvans-cc, length 28
13:17:32.606850 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply cheetah is-at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (oui Unknown), length 28
13:17:45.433222 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has cheetah tell viper, length 28
13:17:45.433243 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply cheetah is-at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (oui Unknown), length 28
13:18:06.065819 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has android-xxx tell viper, length 28
13:18:17.669232 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has viper tell cheetah, length 28
13:18:17.669716 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply viper is-at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (oui Unknown), length 28
13:18:20.631890 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has android-yyy tell viper, length 28
13:18:51.639434 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has cheetah tell viper, length 28
13:18:51.639455 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply cheetah is-at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (oui Unknown), length 28
13:19:02.213231 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has viper tell cheetah, length 28
13:19:02.213762 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply viper is-at xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (oui Unknown), length 28
```

Comment: I know this is quite an old post, but I just wanted to point out that Android 4.4 does *not* ignore ARP queries when connected to a network. However, when the phone's screen is off, as a power saving measure, the device completely disconnects from the network until it is needed, so ARP queries are not even received.